# Is there a way to validate a @RequestHeader against a list of values (from a @configurationproperties)

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring and I am working with an API that receives a country string as a header. I'd like to validate that the string is one of our supported countries using the @Valid annotations.

Currently we're a doing it using a HandlerInterceptorAdapter but we'd like to change this approach for performance gain. Is there an elegant way to validate this header in the controller?

More specifically, the validation would need to get a list of properties configured and check if the header country is in the list.

Something like this for example:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createObject(@RequestBody @Valid final MyRequest myRequest,
            @ApiParam(value = ApiConstants.COUNTRY_HEADER, required = true) @RequestHeader(ApiConstants.COUNTRY_HEADER) @ValidCountry final String country) {

        // call the service
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).build();
    }
```

Comment: Implement a custom validation, see e.g. [Implement custom validators using JSR based validations \[Java 8/Spring\]](https://medium.com/@aman_garg/implement-custom-validators-using-jsr-based-validations-java-8-spring-f06920877916).

Comment: I've tried implementing a custom validation, for eg., implementing a ConstraintValidator but it didn't work

Comment: Show what you tried, so we might help you figure out what is missing to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Spring gives hard times to get JSR303 validation work if all the pieces are not set correctly. I think that the problem is not with the request header but with the configuration somewhere. I present here a minimal example how to configure annotation based configuration.

**Demo controller**

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/endpoint")
    public String createObject(@RequestHeader @ValidCountry String country) {
           return "OK\n";
    }
}
```

**Validator classes** (made the validator as inner class to make it a bit cleaner)

```
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidCountry.CountryValidator.class)
public @interface ValidCountry {
    String message() default "Bad country";
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public static class CountryValidator
            implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCountry, String> {
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String value,
                ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            return null!= value && value.length() > 1;
        }
    }
}
```

To have all this work you also need correct **dependencies** (here is the Maven style):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I am sure you will find a way to put the list of allowed countries for validator to use.

If you test with CURL:

```
curl  -H "country: fi" http://localhost:8080/endpoint
```

will return *OK*.

```
curl  -H "country: f" http://localhost:8080/endpoint
```

will fail.