# Spring boot entity level custom annotation not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, annotations, spring-annotations

So I have a type level custom annotation that checks for matching passwords in a user registration form. Even when the validator is returning false, it doesn't throw an error and show the error message. Any help is appreciated!

Entity class. Annotation in question is @ValidPassword

```
 @Entity
@ValidPassword(fields = {"password", "matchingPassword"})
public class User {
    private String password;
    private String matchingPassword;
```

Constraintvalidator class

```
public class PasswordValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPassword, User> {

    private String[] fields;
    private String message;
    
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(User user, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (fields[0]== null || fields[1] == null) {
        return false;
        }
        for ( String temp : fields) {
        System.out.println(temp);
        }
        boolean flag = Pattern.matches("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$", fields[0]);
        boolean flag1 = fields[0].equals(fields[1]);
        
        if ( !flag1 ) {
            message = "Passwords do not match!";
        }
        
        
         context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message)
                    .addPropertyNode(fields[0]).addConstraintViolation();
            
        return flag && flag1;
        
    }
    
    //Show default message if no special message is set
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidPassword validPassword) {
        
         fields = validPassword.fields();
         message = validPassword.message();
    }

}
```

validpassword

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidPassword {

    String message() default "Please enter at least 8 characters, 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, and 1 special character";
    
    String[] fields();
    
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: Use my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62600638/6413377) as a checklist to exclude the most common problems. Maybe your dependencies are not set correctly?

Comment: @pirho I tried it , didn't work out. I don't think it's dependencies since the other field level custom annotations work

Comment: Ok. One of the reasons could be that your User is not a managed bean? So if you - for example create it like `new User()` that will not trigger the validation? In that case you need to run the validator manually. You might want to add the part where the user is created to your question.

Comment: @pirho I was able to get it working but I have a problem getting the 2 variable into the array. I've updated the code